# Check if boolean value is set in Go

Tags: go, boolean

Is it possible to differentiate between `false` and an unset boolean value in go?

For instance, if I had this code

```
type Test struct {
    Set bool
    Unset bool
}

test := Test{ Set: false }
```

Is there any difference between `test.Set` and `test.Unset` and if so how can I tell them apart?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Which part of the language spec or the Tour of Go makes you think that there are things in Go which are "unset"?

Comment: @Volker: Just out of curiosity: What's the point of being that rude? Don't imply that people can only ask questions here if they have read the complete language spec. This is not how SOF works.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, a bool has two possibilities: `true` or `false`. The default value of an uninitialized bool is `false`. If you want a third state, you can use `*bool` instead, and the default value will be `nil`.

```
type Test struct {
    Set *bool
    Unset *bool
}

f := false
test := Test{ Set: &f }

fmt.Println(*test.Set)  // false
fmt.Println(test.Unset) // nil
```

The cost for this is that it is a bit uglier to set values to literals, and you have to be a bit more careful to dereference (and check nil) when you are using the values.

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/b5HKal2Jc2)

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid there was no difference, but hopefully I can work the pointer solution in without to much pain.

Answer (score 3):

`bool` has a zero value of `false` so there would be no difference between them.

Refer to the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) section of the spec.

What problem are you trying to solve that would require that kind of check?

Answer (score 2):

You may think of using 3-state booleans: https://github.com/grignaak/tribool

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have to use `*bool` instead of primitive `bool`